# How do I easily check if all bools are true in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of bools on every page. I'm writing some validation code and am checking to make sure each bool is true before the user moves on. What is the best way to check to see if all the bools are true or false?

I know I can hard code each one in, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Here are the list of bools:

```
public bool posTitleBool;
public bool firstNameBool;
public bool lastNameBool;
public bool titleBool;
public bool emailBool;
public bool phoneBool;
public bool passwordBool;
public bool passwordValBool;
public bool companyNameBool;
public bool address1Bool;
public bool address2Bool;
public bool cityBool;
public bool stateBool;
public bool zipBool;
public bool industryBool;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Suffixing your field names with the type is a horrible naming convention. I remember doing a code review of some application that used this horror everywhere and for every single variable. After 5 minutes I wanted to vomit. In .NET there are better naming conventions. For example boolean fields could be prefixed with `is` or `has`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options:

- Put them all into a collection and use LINQ (e.g. `conditions.All(x => x)`)
- Simply hardcode

  ```
  postTitleBool && firstNameBool && ...
  ```
- Use reflection to fetch and check each field (are these really public fields, btw? Ick)

You might want to consider using some sort of mapping in the *implementation* so that you've just got a collection of values you can manipulate easily, but then give a property *facade* which gets or sets the right mapped value. Best of both worlds.